# How do you center a templated display control in Bootstrap while maintaining image responsiveness?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a templated display control that I'm trying to put on a grid in Bootstrap.  I can control the HTML and styles in the templated display but not the HTML surrounding it, the grid sizes, nor the image source.

The template contains a left-justified header with a responsive image:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vitae mattis diam. Aliquam sodales urna non urna accumsan, eget tempus arcu viverra. Vestibulum dui risus, eleifend vel aliquam ...
            <!-- Start repeated code element -->
            <div id="center-me" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: table; border: 1px solid blue;">
                <h4 id="must-be-lined-up-with-image">Left Justified Header</h4>
                <img id="must-be-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/ISRUCaV.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <!-- End repeated code element -->
            Ut fermentum neque elit, nec ultricies est ultrices ac. Ut luctus purus ac mi euismod sodales. Aliquam auctor posuere sodales. Proin sed nulla condimentum, tempor arcu ut, congue elit. Cras ... 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <!-- Start repeated code element -->
            <div id="Div1" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: table; border: 1px solid blue;">
                <h4 id="H1">Left Justified Header</h4>
                <img id="Img1" src="http://i.imgur.com/ISRUCaV.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <!-- End repeated code element -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <!-- Start repeated code element -->
            <div id="Div2" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: table; border: 1px solid blue;">
                <h4 id="H2">Left Justified Header</h4>
                <img id="Img2" src="http://i.imgur.com/ISRUCaV.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <!-- End repeated code element -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <!-- Start repeated code element -->
            <div id="Div3" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: table; border: 1px solid blue;">
                <h4 id="H3">Left Justified Header</h4>
                <img id="Img3" src="http://i.imgur.com/ISRUCaV.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <!-- End repeated code element -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are additional requirements on the template itself:

- The header must be left-justified and lined up with the image
- The image cannot exceed 100%
- The container for the header and image must be centered on the page
- If the image is larger than the grid size, it must shrink down appropriately to fit in the grid

**This screenshot is the exact layout that needs to be achieved.**

It looks great in Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

But it doesn't work on Firefox or IE at all:

[image: Firefox]

I've created an example on Bootply of what I'm trying to achieve: http://www.bootply.com/ZSNbC15oyA

Comment: I added some additional requirements that were set on the templated control.  Basically, the first screenshot is what the solution should look like, but in all 3 browsers.  If it's not possible with HTML/CSS alone, we do have the option of using JQuery, although that is less desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After being unable to find a suitable pure-CSS solution, I found one using jQuery that works in those browsers:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".img-responsive").each(function (index, element) {
        $(element).css("max-width", $(element).closest("div[class^='col-'],div[class*=' col-']").innerWidth());
    });
});
```

(Note: A real implementation would use a better selector than ".img-responsive")

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer is really easy: you just remove those `DIV` elements you added to kill responsiveness of column grids

```
<div id="Div1" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: table; border: 1px solid blue;">
```

and as we're at it, you can remove the same ID for all images and replace for classes for easier manipulation, so add teh following CSS

```
.col-xs-4 .myBox, .col-xs-12 .myBox{border: 1px solid blue; margin:10px auto; width:90%}
.must-be-responsive{width:100%; height:auto;}
```

Anyways, take a look at this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/jREHU2bGBN) I forked from your example

**Explanation:**

Usually people feels tempted to mess around with Bootstrap positioning system, when in fact, the strength of Bootstrap is its positioning system, so when we think in a layout, we must think in terms of the BS grids, then, how we want to style those grids.

If we need additional styling with margins and spacing, we know margins will affect the grid system, so chances are this styling will come from additional elements added inside the grids. So in this particular case, I have added a div with class `.myBox` which has the blue border, 90% width and an horizontal margin property of `auto` just to make sure it will fit in any width

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't achieve the desired effect because it stretches the image beyond 100% and doesn't center the block.  In other words, it doesn't match the layout in the first screenshot.  The IDs are all fake some of theme were auto-generated by Bootply.

Comment: I thought yo mean only the positioning, see the edit , the bootply is new so visit the new link.

Comment: It looks great, except you cheated by hardcoding the width to 90%. ;)  http://www.bootply.com/tDwvUdz2XV  If I swap out the image source, it exceeds 100% of the image.  It should look like this (in Chrome): http://www.bootply.com/EEktQJecT3

Comment: sorry, not getting you... I'm not "cheating", whatever you consider it cheating, I'm coding something according to the exact premises you posted. If you want that border in the image, you replace the .myBox behavior for an image, I took some time to explain how the inner elements behave, so use it in image or whatever. Also, it's pretty unexpected that you'll use a 1 column element as that kitten in a full 12 column grid, so again, I can only do things based on a brief, but I provided the tools to modify everything at will

Comment: In the first sentence, I state I can't control the image source.  This means the image could be from whatever and be whatever size.  It's why I can't predict and hardcode a specific "width: ###px" and solve this problem that way. :(  And yes, I agree the example looks dumb and unrealistic, but that's because I slapped together a simplistic example.

Comment: The end-user is able to control the bootstrap grid sizes, the HTML inside the grid, and then plop down this "thumbnail-like" templated control (which is more than just the header and image, but again, I simplified it for this site) and align it to the center.  If the image isn't responsive or constrained somehow, it breaks the rest of the site by overlapping.

Comment: I do appreciate the effort though.  I thought perhaps there was an easy keyword I was missing somewhere so I tried not to get too wordy into the backstory of this thing, but I think that just confused a lot of people.

Comment: yes, very simple: you don't use a bootstrap grid for that row, as easy as that, so you leave the image without col..... . It seems you didn't read my explanation or maybe it I'm not making myself clear, so here it goes again: *Bootstrap is a positioning system, what you do with the elements inside will depend on your needs. Just because you have columns or grids, it doesn't mean you HAVE to use them *

Comment: I am reading what you're saying, but you're not listening to me (or reading the very first sentence of this question): I don't control the HTML outside of the templated display control.  The end-user and the application generates all that.  The size-12 column grid is just a very simplified example that's easiest to test and demonstrate.  But it could very well use "md-6 lg-4" grids or whatever the user decides.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue comes from the **display: table;** CSS property - browsers have some differences in rendering tables, so unless you need it for something specific its useless when you just need a CSS grid as you are using bootstrap's columns.

Comment: I don't need "display: table" if there's a solution that can achieve the same look as the first screenshot without using it.

Comment: I removed the display:table and it did render the page as your first screenshot in firefox.

Comment: Also to center the first image just put **center-block** class to it and expand it with **width: 100%;**

Answer (score 0):

Add class .img-centered to your img tag

```
.img-centered{
       margin:0 auto;
       float : none;
       display:block;
}
```

it centered your image